# Software not available in the new Ubuntu version (15.04)

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I'm a Ubuntu 14.04 user and I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04, but there's a software that I bought  in 14.04 that is not showing anymore on Ubuntu Software Center. What to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Tell us the name of the software.